# AngularJs watchCollection for JSON object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

Actually i have one JSON which is having array of objects collections. I'm binding that JSON values to controls(input).

I trying to give value in the input field which is firing first time.
If i will change or edit existing value it's not firing. but values changing in the model.

JSON: I am binding the collections object to $watchCollection

```
{
  "entityinfo": {
    "entity": "Customer29Jan16",
    "tenantid": "292FEC76-5F1C-486F-85A5-09D88096F098",
    "timestamp": "2015-12-15T10:16:06.322Z"
  },
  "collections": {
    "customer29jan16": {
      "rowset": [
        {
          "cuid": "6293f82f-d202-45c0-9a7b-46cd955361a3",
          "name": "test",
          "quantity": "60",
          "rate": "60",
          "amount": "3600"
        }
      ],
      "meta": {
        "parentreference": "***",
        "pkname": "***",
        "fkname": "***"
      },
      "rowfilter": []
    }
  }
}
```

Controller code:

```
bosAppModule.controller("module-menu-controller", function($scope, $compile, $http) {   
    $scope.transactionalData={};
    $scope.transactionalData.Data={"entityinfo":{"entity":"Customer29Jan16","tenantid":"292FEC76-5F1C-486F-85A5-09D88096F098","timestamp":"2015-12-15T10:16:06.322Z"},"collections":{"customer29jan16":{"rowset":[{"cuid":"6293f82f-d202-45c0-9a7b-46cd955361a3","name":"test","quantity":"60","rate":"60","amount":"3600"}],"meta":{"parentreference":"***","pkname":"***","fkname":"***"},"rowfilter":[]},"customer29jan16obj":{"rowset":[{"cuobjid":"83bfc652-9f83-47d3-b173-b1a824ff3bed","fulladdress":"Electronic City","objaddr":"Bangalore","objname":"Testing","customer29jan16objcuid":"6293f82f-d202-45c0-9a7b-46cd955361a3"}],"meta":{"parentreference":"***","pkname":"***","fkname":"***"},"rowfilter":[]}}}


$scope.$watchCollection('transactionalData.Data.collections', function( newValue, oldValue ) {                        
                            console.log(newValue, oldValue);
                           // return;                       
            });
});
```

Comment: can you explain more or attach a plunker?

Comment: @YatinGera - sorry to say  Mine is complete dynamically creating controls(input). It's very tough to create examples in pluner. But i will try my best to create. Please have look my explanation now i added more.

Comment: @YatinGera - I create one sample in fiddle. please have look http://jsfiddle.net/bagya1985/bhraxk0z/5/

Comment: You could use a watch with a deep watch
http://jsfiddle.net/bhraxk0z/7/

Comment: deep watch are expensive though....how big is your actual json?

Comment: @YatinGera - My actual JSON i can't say how much big it will come. because it will form dynamically. I could say it's depends on user.

Comment: @YatinGera - I have another one doubt. How to add flag like operationContext: "update". when ever changes happening on particular value. and when ever adding new value to that json. i need to add  operationContext: "add". For example  {
          "cuid": "6293f82f-d202-45c0-9a7b-46cd955361a3",
          "name": "test",
          "quantity": "60",
          "rate": "60",
          "amount": "3600",
        "operationContext":"Update"
        }

Comment: @YatinGera - Can you please give solution for my previous comment/issue.

Comment: If that is what you need then you might not even have to add a deep watch. 
This might help
http://jsfiddle.net/bhraxk0z/9/

Comment: @YatinGera Yeah I agree but this will work for Normal form. In my case kendo grid also there. The same set of JSON object collection we are binding with kendo grid also. So how can bind this triggerChange method to grid column. $watch is working fine as i expected for kendo grid also. Only thing is i am not able to get the index, i mean which value is got changed. there i need operationContext. I hope you got my point. Please help in this regards..Thanks in advance.

Comment: i believe, there should be a method to set row template in kendo

Comment: @YatinGera can you provide any example for that or please suggest me using $watch only.

Comment: @YatinGera  I would like to tell you the kendo grid is dynamically we are forming and we can't say how many grids will come. If it's static grid i can get the changes. Here we are doing everything object based. when ever the model changes it's should reflect the $scope. Finally we are sending $scope value to server directly. We shouldn't read grid data $("#grid").data('kendoGrid').dataSource.data(); That's the reason i'm asking , need to do in $scope itself. Please give me suggestion on this regards.

Comment: @YatinGera - Trigger change not working real time code. Please help me how can i add operationContext using $watch

Comment: I cannot really think of finding which element in the list got changed by using watch as of now.

Comment: @YatinGera . Sorry for disturb again. is it possible to add operationContext in newValu at the time editing.. I tried using angular.equals .it will return only boolean value.